# Is there a way to change the height to fill the rest area?

Tags: html, css

Now, I need to set the '#bottomshow' div's height full of the rest of the device screen.
At first, I use `rem` to set the style. The '#bg' and the '#topSelector',I set the height with `rem`.
How to set the '#bottomshow' match the full empty of the screen. In other words, I need to set the HTML to fill the full mobile phone screen.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.76rem;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

#topSelector {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 242, 242);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: .44rem;
}

#bottomShow {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="topSelector"></div>
<div id="bottomShow">
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/mobileRemSet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  mobileRemSet(window, 375);
</script>
```

This is my code above. `mobileRemSet(window,375);` is to set the rem unit. Now I set the `bottomShow` height `40px`. Is there a way to change its height to fill the rest area?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321492/css-set-size-of-div-to-fill-remaining-space?s=6|105.6203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work out for you -

Just set the height using `calc()`

`#bottomShow` height = calc(`100vh` - `#bg` height + `#topSelector` height);

in CSS it would be like.

```
 #bottomShow {
   height:calc(100vh - 2.16rem);
}
```

**Working sample for you.**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.76rem;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

#topSelector {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 242, 242);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: .44rem;
}

#bottomShow {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:calc(100vh - 2.16rem);
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="topSelector"></div>
<div id="bottomShow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox to work it out. Run the below snippet and you'll understand. `flex-grow: 1` will basically give all the remaining height to the third child.

```css
.p {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c1, .c2 {
  height: .44rem;
  background-color: green;
}

.c3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">

  <div class="c1"></div>
  <div class="c2"></div>
  <div class="c3"></div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it helps.